# C# application execution tracking

Tags: c#, debugging

I have 2 builds of a simple C# application, one runs as expected, but the second often does not.

There is some way to track and compare differences in the execution of these two apps (what .dll files used, or differences in code execution when certain method is called)?

Comment: Sure, that is called logging :-)

Comment: You are talking about already compiled code that cannot be edited?...does the program have logging?   Does it display the stacktrace?   Do you have the pdbs for the build?

Comment: Easy, write flight recoders to 2 files then use visual studio compare dll to show diffs in VS.

Comment: If you can't edit the source then use Sysinternals' [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/downloads/procmon)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, logging is indeed the answer. As a great starting point, I would recommend that you check out the [Easy.Common](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.Common) library that has an excellent [DiagnosticReport](https://github.com/NimaAra/Easy.Common/blob/master/Easy.Common/DiagnosticReport/DiagnosticReport.cs) utility that will log a bunch of key information about your application, (including all assemblies), as well as the target environment.

See [Stuff Every .NET App Should be Logging at Startup](http://www.nimaara.com/2017/11/07/stuff-every-dotnet-app-should-be-logging-at-startup/) for additional details

This is how I use it, with [Serilog](https://serilog.net/)

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Debug()
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .WriteTo.RollingFile(expandedLogFilePath, outputTemplate: fileOutputTemplate, retainedFileCountLimit: 14)
    .Enrich.With(new NormalizedSourceContextEnricher())
    .Enrich.WithThreadId()
    .CreateLogger();

logger = Log.ForContext<App>();
DiagnosticReport report = DiagnosticReport.Generate();
var reportString = report.ToString();
logger.Information(reportString);
```

(I don't want to include my sample DiagnosticReport output as is contains some info that may be sensitive)